# Svelte: How do I call a function in a child component after switching to it using a dynamic component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have a `<svelte:component>` in my parent component that allows me to switch between multiple child components. I want to call a function inside one of the child components. To do this, I have a function in the parent component that first tries to switch to that child component and then calls the function.

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import First from './First.svelte'
    import Second from './Second.svelte'
    
    let selected = First;
    let child;
    
    function secondHello() {
        selected = Second;
        child.hello();
    }
</script>

...

<svelte:component this={selected} bind:this={child}/>
```

Second.svelte

```
<script>
    export function hello() {
        //do stuff
    }
</script>
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/93214917d7414741a229cd81267287b7?version=3.38.3

The problem is that when the current selected component is not `Second`, the function `secondHello` doesn't work. It seems like it takes some time for `child` to update after changing `selected`, causing `child.hello();` to raise an error because it doesn't exist in the other child component.

Is there some way to wait for `child` to update? Or should I be using a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is right that `child.hello()` fires too soon, since Svelte did not flush the updates yet, therefore `bind:this={child}` did not update `child` yet. For situations like this, Svelte provides the `tick` method which lets you wait until any pending state updates are applied to the DOM:

```
<script>
    import { tick } from 'svelte'
    import First from './First.svelte'
    import Second from './Second.svelte'
    
    let selected = First;
    let child;
    
    function secondHello() {
        selected = Second;
        tick().then(() => child.hello());
    }
    
    // or:
    async function secondHello() {
        selected = Second;
        await tick();
        child.hello();
    }
</script>

...

<svelte:component this={selected} bind:this={child}/>
```

Tutorial on tick: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick